# Javascript: Variable gets trimmed when assigned

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a variable `row['case']` returned from AJAX which is equal to "Hello World!". The problem is that when I try to assign it to another variable, only "Hello" is getting assigned, `row['case'] = "Hello"`, instead of `row['case'] = "Hello World!"`.

Here's the block of code where the issue is present:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#peacecard').DataTable({
    "ajax": "http://localhost:8080/peace_reports/data.php",
    "columns": [
      {
        "className":      'details-control',
        "orderable":      false,
        "data":           null,
        "defaultContent": ''
      },
      { "data": "Name" },
      { "data": "Vendor", "className": 'dt-right' }
      { "data": "case", "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                                    if (data == "true"){ 
                                      data = "<i title="+row['case2']+" id='thei'; } 
                                    else { data = ""; }
                                    return data; }, 
                                    "className": 'dt-center'}
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
  });
```

This is what console.log(row) shows:

```
Object {Vendor: "123", Name: "MyHome", case2: "Hello World!"}
```

Comment: Please include a block of code where this problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Are you *sure* `row['case']` contains `"Hello World!"`?  What does `console.log(row);` show?  Can you show us how you are creating `row` (the PHP and the AJAX call)?  We'll need to see your code to be able to help here.

Comment: Without source I have no idea but if you also program the service which returns the ajax - you could URLEncode your answer, then you dont have the ' '. And then you have to decode afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes and a `</i>` on this line:

```
data = "<i title="+row['case2']+" id='thei';
```

It should be something like:

```
data = "<i title='"+row['case2']+"' id='thei'></i>";
```